# How to look for a form after URL redirect with mechanize and python

Tags: python, mechanize

So here is my problem, in order to fill a form on a website I have to log me in on a page then get redirected.

I manage to fill the login form and submit it with this code:

```
from mechanize import Browser
import mechanize
from mechanize._opener import urlopen
from mechanize._form import ParseResponse
from sys import argv

br = Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)   
br.set_handle_refresh(False)  
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

USERNAME = 'my_username'
PASSWORD = 'my_password'
URL      = "my_url"

request = mechanize.Request(URL)
response = mechanize.urlopen(request)
forms = mechanize.ParseResponse(response, backwards_compat=False)

form = forms[0]

form["Email"] = USERNAME
form["Passwd"] = PASSWORD

x = urlopen(form.click()).read () 

print x
```

When I print `x` I get the html code of the redirected page (that's good my submit works and I am logged in). 
But now I want to fill the form on the page i get redirected in. I do not managed to find the form on this URL. An idea/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where u able to solve this ?

Comment: Then how did u managed this issue.....any work around?

Comment: I managed a solution with Selenium to log in and get the second page, then I used the mechanize to fill the second form. I will document it later when I will have time.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> x = br.submit().read()

instead of

> x = urlopen(form.click()).read ()